# How to set SQL Server Connection pool size

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, connection-string, connection-pooling

I am using `Hibernate` with a `Java` web application and I want to set the limit the `SQL Server 2005` connection pool size. As far as I have read I have to use a connection string.
Can I specify it in the `hibernate.properties` or in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`?
Are there mandatory fields or can I just specify the `Max Pool Size`?

**EDIT:**
I would like to reproduce an error that came from a production machine:

```
2011-02-07 17:52:00,282 ERROR [STDERR] [WARN] JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2011-02-07 17:52:00,282 ERROR [STDERR] [ERROR] JDBCExceptionReporter - I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2011-02-07 17:52:00,282 ERROR [STDERR] [ERROR] JDBCTransaction - JDBC rollback failed <java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.>java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.checkOpen(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1634)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.rollback(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2027)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:162)
```

Comment: why do you think you need to change the pool size?

Comment: Do remember that the Hibernate default connection pool is not for production use as is stated in the docs. Johan Sjöbergs anwser below is good

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I have received an error log with an SQLState: 08S01 JDBC rollback failed error, which I want to reproduce locally.

Comment: @Erik: Thanks for the comment. I have also seen the Hibernate docs, but I want to see what exactly is causing the error. It may be that I am using the non-production mode, but if I can not figure out the source of the problem I can not test the solution.

Comment: This may sound silly but have you tried 'hibernate.connection.pool_size=<desired value>' in hibernate.properties (or is it in hibernate.cfg.xml?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using e.g., [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) you can configure pool size by `maxPoolSize` property, e.g.:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="...." />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="..."/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="..." />
</bean>
```

Comment: I am not using c3p0. Is there a possibility to do it without using c3p0?

Comment: Not unless using a library such as c3p0. This is pretty clear simply by looking at the APIs.